# RecyclerView Doesn't Update The List After Adding New Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am fresher in android coding.
I am in a  project that using tablayout, viewpager 2, fragements, bottom navigation
I designed two fragments, each in a tab, one for inputting items (fragment 1 in tab 1), one to show the items with a recyclerview.
The data will be stored with (and get from) Room Database.
I meet a trouble, the input items can not show immediately on recyclerview (in fragment 2, in tab 2), it has to restart the app to see it updated, noted that in the input fragment there is a toast message shows that it is done stored the items in its database.

Could you please help me to find out where i am stucking with the code ? I appreciate a lot :-*

```
View mView;
EditText addTitle;
EditText addContent;
ImageButton btnSave;

public WriteFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_write, container, false);

    addTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_add_title);
    addContent = mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_add_content);
    btnSave = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { addItems();

        }
    });





    hideSoftKeyboard();
    return mView;
}

private void addItems() {

    String strTitle = addTitle.getText().toString().trim(); //trim dùng để xóa ký tự trắng ở đầu và cuối trong edittext
    String strContent = addContent.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strTitle)|| TextUtils.isEmpty(strContent)){
        return;
    }
    ItemsObject itemsObject = new ItemsObject(strTitle,strContent);
    MainActivity.diaryDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).userDAO().insert(itemsObject);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Successfully Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //thêm dữ liệu thành công thì cần phải reset hint trong trường nhập dữ liệu:
    addTitle.setText("");
    addContent.setText("");
    hideSoftKeyboard(); //ẩn bàn phím ảo


}



public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

```
code in fragment 2:
package com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes.fragments.diary_tabs;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes.ItemsAdapter;
import com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes.ItemsObject;
import com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes.MainActivity;
import com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DiaryLogFragment extends Fragment {

    View mView;
    private RecyclerView rcvItems;
    private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
    private List<ItemsObject> itemsObjectList;


    public DiaryLogFragment(){

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diary_log, container, false);

        rcvItems =mView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_items);
        itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter();

        itemsObjectList = DiaryDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).userDAO().getListUser(); //hiển thị danh sách
        itemsAdapter.setData(itemsObjectList);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rcvItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rcvItems.setFocusable(true);
        rcvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);






        return mView;

    }

}
```

```
package com.haki.mysimplehakidiarynotes;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

    private List<ItemsObject> mListItems;


    public void setData(List<ItemsObject> list) {
        this.mListItems =list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();



    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.layout_items, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemsObject itemsObject =mListItems.get(position);
        if (itemsObject==null){
            return;
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemsObject.getTitle());
        holder.txtContent.setText(itemsObject.getContent());

        holder.foldingCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.foldingCell.toggle(false);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if (mListItems!=null){
            return mListItems.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        FoldingCell foldingCell;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtContent;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            foldingCell =itemView.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);
            txtTitle =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            txtContent =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

        }


    }




}
```

Comment: if data is successfully inserted then, you need to pass that updated data to Recyclerview adapter and call notifyItemInserted()/removed() inside the adapter

Comment: Hey, the problem is that this code indeed adds new item to the database, but you are not listening for DB changes. You are retrieving current list of objects when a fragment in created. 
You should consider changing
DiaryDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).userDAO().getListUser()
in a way that it returns LiveData<List< ItemsObject>> instead of List< ItemsObject> so you will be able to observe updates

Comment: thanks bongo for your recommendation, could you please look on the code and show me an demo ? i appreciate for that

Comment: Update for resolution: to those who has the same problem, this relate to the fragment life cycle, it needs to call the list again once after input new data, so in the adapter should define the context and the list, in the fragment which shows the list should call the for the resume.